# Como puedo hacerle para que la animacion se haga cuando le di click en el boton submit?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

El scipt que tengo no esta funcionando, y no se porque. Quiero que la animacion de CSS se haga despues que le di click en boton de submit.

El scipt que tengo no esta funcionando, y no se porque. Quiero que la animacion de CSS se haga despues que le di click en boton de submit.

Ahorita lo que esta haciendo es que la animacion se esta haciendo cuando se carga la pagina.

Ahorita lo que esta haciendo es que la animacion se esta haciendo cuando se carga la pagina.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#submitButton").on('click', function(){
         $("#div1").addclass('animation');
    })
});
```

```css
.animation {
    position: relative;
    animation: mymove 2s;
}
@keyframes mymove {
from {
top: 0px;
}
to {
top: 300px;
}
}
.form2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
<title>Comentarios</title>

<body>
    <h3 class="text-center mt-3 font-weight-bolder ">Comments</h3>
<div  class="container pt-5" >
  
  <div id="div1" class="d-flex justify-content-center container-sm p-4 ">
    <form  class="form1" >
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputName">Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputLastName1">Apellido</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_paterno"  id="apellido_paterno" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="" id="email"  required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="rating">Rating</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="rating_stars"  required>
            <option selected disabled value="">Escoge...</option>
            <option>1 estrella</option>
            <option>2 estrellas</option>
            <option>3 estrellas</option>
            <option>4 estrellas</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"  name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center  p-3 ">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md font-weight-normal" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
        <div class="p-4"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Quita la clase _animation_ del div.

Comment: El problema mas grande es que tu boton es de tipo submit, y pues recuerda que al ser un boton de tipo submit el formulario sera enviado, y al ser enviado el formulario no le da tiempo a la animacion de que esta se reproduzca, por tanto debes considerar no usar un boton de tipo submit o en su defecto cancelar el evento de tipo submit, ponerle un retraso para esperar a la animacion y luego cuando se haya terminado la animacion hacer un submit manual desde el evento cancelado.

Comment: Ya le quite el type=submit al boton pero sigue haciendo la animacion al cargar la pagina, y no cuando le doy click al boton. :(

Comment: Solo cambiaste la clase _animation_ del div al form, ahora es el formulario el que ejecuta la animación. Asegúrate de que ningún elemento tiene esa clase al cargar la página.

Comment: ahh okay, ya hice el cambio. Aunque sigue sin hacer la animacion cuando el doy  clic en el  boton submit.

Comment: ¿No te dio problemas escribir `$("#div1").addclass('animation');` en lugar de `$("#div1").addClass('animation');`?

Comment: No, pero ya lo cambie en mi codigo, gracias.